# infiniteness of completely split primes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, ramification

Let $K ⊂ L$ number fields. Prove that there are infinitely many primes of K that split completely in $L$.

My attempt:

Using this question: [Infinitely many primes in the ring of integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245487/infinitely-many-primes-in-the-ring-of-integers) , we know there are infinitely many primes $\mathfrak  p$ in $K$ such that inertia degree is $f (\mathfrak  p|p) = 1$.

Consider a normal extension $M/L$ (of finite degree over $L$).

Then there are infinitely many primes $\mathfrak  q_i$ in $M$ such that inertia degree is $f (\mathfrak  q_i|p_i) = 1$.

All the primes $p_i\in \Bbb Z$ lying under those primes $\mathfrak q_i$ such that $p_i> Disc(M)$ do not ramify in $M$ since $p\nmid Disc(M)$.

Let $p_i=\prod_{i=1}^r \mathfrak q_i$ be the splitting in $M$ of such a prime, hence:
$\forall i\in \{1,...,r\} e(\mathfrak q_i|p_i)=e(\mathfrak q_1|p_1)=1$  since $M$ is normal (all ramification indices are equal).

Now taking the primes $\mathfrak p_i, i=1...s, s<r$ we have the splitting in $L$ of the $p_i$'s:

$p_i=\prod_{i=1}^r \mathfrak p_i^{e_i}$ with $ \forall i, \mathfrak p_i\in L$

By multiplicativity of ramification indices in field extensions, $\forall i, e_i|1 \Rightarrow  e_i=1$ .

Hence taking all the primes in $K$ lying under the $\mathfrak p_i's$ there are infinitely many primes in K that split completely in $L$ since $[L:K]=efs=s$.

Thank you for any comments or help in this elementary proof.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Notice that the claim follows immediately by Chebotarev density theorem.