# Application of Chevotarev density theorem, 'prime elements' vs 'prime ideals'

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of number fields. Does there
> infinitely many **prime elements of $K$** which splits completely in $L/K$
> ?

**Chevotarev density theorem** claims there are infinitely many **prime ideals of $K$** which splits completely in $L/K$. But I think the  above statement does not follow directly from this **because ring of integers of $K$ need not to be PID**.
How can I prove the above statement from Chevotarev density theorem ?

I saw the above statement in this comment of Ferra,

''Notice that the claim follows immediately by Chebotarev density theorem.''

:
[infiniteness of completely split primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436308/infiniteness-of-completely-split-primes)

Comment: Apply Chebotarev to the Hilbert class field of $L$.

Comment: Thank you, @franz lemmermeyer, for the insight. It was an eye-opener for me. In the Hilbert class field $H$ of $L$, the class number is $1$, and we can apply the Chebotarev Density Theorem to $H/K$. This implies that there are infinitely many prime ideals of $K$ that split in $H/K$. Consequently, thanks to the fact that class number of $H$ is $1$, this means there are infinitely many prime elements in $K$ that also split in $H/K$. Therefore, they should also split in $L/K$. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: The prime ideals in $K$ (really, in $\mathcal O_K$) that split completely in the Hilbert class field $H$ of $K$ are precisely the principal prime ideals in $K$, and those are the prime ideals you are asking about.